# Getting no caustics

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, caustics

[image: A test render]

Above is a quick test render to see if caustics were working in the scene, and to my disappointment I'm getting nothing. I checked several tutorial videos to make sure I was doing everything right: the sun light is set to enable caustics, the glass is set to cast caustics, and the table is set to receive caustics. I also tried another render without the liquid in the glass, but that didn't help. The pool in the background is also having the same problem.

In an unrelated note, the refraction also seems wrong, based on how the straw is looking.

I added a simplified blend of just the table, glass, and a kiddie pool, to demonstrate the problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you have enough light bounces in your render settings (**Render Settings > Light Paths > Max Bounces**)? Sometimes not having a sufficient amount of light bounces can cause this depending on the complexity of the scene. Adding the blend file to the question will help us to take a closer look. You can use: [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Comment: I agree we have to take a look at the file, because from your information it seems as if you have done everything correct and it is not easy to determine where the error could be then. As e3_productions said, maybe it's the light bounces... to me the render looks a bit like it's _Eevee_, not _Cycles_ (but of course you could not have set the caustics options then), so the light bounces might be (one of) the problem(s). The shadow of the glass seems strangely opaque.

Comment: Have you tested caustics at a new file (plane, cylinder, sun strength 3, black world) with setup you mentioned above? If it works (works for me) issue lays in your scene setup ... for that you should share your simplified file, just in stage we can see the issue. Use https://blend-exchange.com ... BTW your glass object is using Shade > Smooth, right?